# Ubuntu doesn't recognize specific package through apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I'm trying to install `libboost-thread1.54.0` (I need this specific version) using this command: `sudo apt-get install libboost-thread1.54.0` but it throws me this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package libboost-thread1.54.0 
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libboost-thread1.54.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libboost-thread1.54.0'
```

However, I find the package [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libboost-thread1.54.0), it seems that Ubuntu doesn't recognize it.

In the same page, in the right panel there are download links but I don't know really which one it's for me.
Can't find any direct answer in google either. I really need that package installed, I know there are newer versions but I need that one.

Working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

PS: I have [this](https://www.biostars.org/p/163067/) error, thats why I need the libboost-thread1.54.0

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct repo(s) enabled?  Perhaps copy in your repo list?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: I ran `sudo apt-get update`, same error. I also try with `libboost-thread1.54-dev`, it throws me this error: Package libboost-thread1.54-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libboost-thread1.54-dev' has no installation candidate

Comment: oh sorry, I very lazily did not read that you're using 16.04. You can go [here for 64-bit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/amd64/libboost-thread1.54.0/download) or [here for 32-bit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/i386/libboost-thread1.54.0/download) and download the .deb package from a local mirror, then go to the directory with the file (`cd Downloads` for example) and do `sudo dpkg -i name-of-package.deb` (replace with actual name)

Comment: Thanks! I installed it and it worked fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Version 1.58 of libboost-thread exists in Ubuntu 16.04. Install it by typing the following in a Terminal Window:

```
sudo apt install libboost-thread1.58.0
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the 1.54 version for a program that work with it. It doesn't work or recognize any other versions.

Comment: It seems that  version 1.54 is available for Ubuntu 16.04 as part of a repository. You could try to compile it from source.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Y PPA? [Link to Y PPA info](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/01/graphical-tool-add-remove-purge-ppa/)

It sorted my last "package not found" issue, allowing me to search all PPA's for the package I wanted.

to install;

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```